# Custom collision shape appears in wrong position

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I load an `Entity` from Reality Composer and I add a custom `CollisionShape`.

These are the steps I follow:

```swift
// I get the `.reality` url and I load the model
let rocketSceneUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Experience", 
                                   withExtension: "reality")!
                                        .appending(path: "RocketScene", 
                                          directoryHint: .notDirectory)

let rocketScene = try Entity.load(contentsOf: rocketSceneUrl)

// I get the visual bounds of the `boxScene`
let visualBounds = rocketScene.visualBounds(
                                  recursive: true, 
                                 relativeTo: self, 
                            excludeInactive: false)

// I generate the custom shape resource. 
// I use the y for the height, and half the boundingRadius
let shapeResource = ShapeResource.generateCapsule(
                                    height: bounds.extents.y, 
                                    radius: bounds.boundingRadius / 2)

// I create the custom `CollisionComponent`
let collision = CollisionComponent(
                            shapes: [shapeResource], 
                              mode: .trigger, 
                            filter: .sensor)

// I set the component on the `Entity`
rocketScene.components.set(collision)

// Then I add the `Entity` in the scene.
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

The `Entity` with its collision shape appears below the actual content, or conversely the actual content appears above the `Entity` and its custom collision shape.

I guess that when RealityKit adds the `Entity` on a surface, it compensates by moving the contents in such a way so that it appears to be sitting on the plane, but I may be mistaken.

**My question is how do I make the custom collision shape be at the same location where the contents of the `Entity` are?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Repositioning a ShapeResource's mesh

Your Custom Collision Shape's mesh is properly placed in the RealityKit's scene because its center perfectly matches the model's [pivot point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975867/arcore-model-showing-above-face/55979837#55979837) position. To reposition your `shapeResource`, use the [offsetBy(translation:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73287427/applying-downward-force-to-an-object-using-realitykit/73648884#73648884) modifier to move it along `+Y` direction.

```
@MainActor func offsetBy(translation: SIMD3<Float>) -> ShapeResource
```

Here's a code:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 
        arView.debugOptions = .showPhysics
        
        let entity = try! Entity.load(named: "Rocket.reality")
        
        let bounds = entity.visualBounds(recursive: true,
                                        relativeTo: nil,
                                   excludeInactive: false)
        
        var shapes: ShapeResource = ShapeResource.generateCapsule(
                                           height: bounds.extents.y,
                                           radius: bounds.boundingRadius / 2)
                                    .offsetBy(translation: [0, 0.5, 0])
                                       
        let collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [shapes],
                                             mode: .trigger,
                                           filter: .sensor)    
        entity.components.set(collision)
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76177006/collider-does-not-works-properly-in-realitykit/76180997#76180997) may be helpful for you.