# RealityKit auto-generated collision box appearing below the model

Tags: swiftui, realitykit

I'm trying to load a rigged 3D model in RealityKit. I was able to load it but the auto generated collision box is placed under the model. And I'm trying to move the model when a button is pressed.

How can I do it in RealityKit?

Is it possible to move a 3D model on the detected plane in RealityKit?

[image: Here is what I'm getting]

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import Combine

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var yOffset: Float = 0.0
    
    @State var btnPressed = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ARViewContainer(yOffset: $yOffset)
            Button {
                btnPressed.toggle()
                yOffset += 0.1
                arView.arView.debugOptions = btnPressed ? [] : 
                                [.showPhysics,.showFeaturePoints,.showAnchorOrigins]
            } label: {
                Text("Show Debug")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var yOffset: Float
    
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        arView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(
                             target: context.coordinator,
                             action: #selector(context.coordinator.handleTap)))
        context.coordinator.arview = arView
                    
//        let boxMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.05)
//        let boxMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: UIColor.red, isMetallic: true)
//        let boxEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: boxMesh, materials: [boxMaterial])
//        boxEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
//        let planeAnchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
//        planeAnchor.addChild(boxEntity)
//        arView.scene.addAnchor(planeAnchor)
        return arView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        if let modelEntity = uiView.scene.anchors.compactMap({ $0 as? ModelEntity }).first {
                   modelEntity.position.y += yOffset
               }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ARCoordinator {
        return ARCoordinator()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

class ARCoordinator: NSObject {
    
    var arview: ARView?
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if let arview {
            let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: arview)
            arview.debugOptions = [.showPhysics]
//            if let tappedEntity = arview.entity(at: tapLocation) as? ModelEntity {
//                tappedEntity.model?.materials = [SimpleMaterial(color: UIColor.purple, isMetallic: true)]
//            }
           let results = arview.raycast(from: tapLocation, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal)
            if let hitResult = results.first{
                //                let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: hitResult)
                //                let boxMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.2)
                //                let boxMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: UIColor.red, isMetallic: true)
                //                let boxEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: boxMesh, materials: [boxMaterial])
                //    anchorEntity.addChild(boxEntity)
                //                boxEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                //                arview.installGestures(.all, for: boxEntity)
                
                let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: hitResult)
                cancellable =  ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: "Evangelion_-_Eva_01_Rigged")
                    .sink { [self] result  in
                        switch result {
                        case .finished:
                            print("Finished")
                            cancellable?.cancel()
                            break
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print(error)
                            break 
                        }
                    } receiveValue: { modelEnity in
                        modelEnity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
                
                        anchorEntity.addChild(modelEnity)
                        arview.installGestures(.all, for: modelEnity)
                        arview.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Collision shape pose

This is a well known issue. Your model's collision shape is in the "right" place because the collision shape is created around the model's pivot point. Also, hidden elements of the model located at some distance from it can affect the location of the Collision Shape. In Reality Composer, check where the pivot of the model is located and how it's oriented. If you're not able to offset the model's pivot point in 3D authoring software (like Autodesk Maya), then move/rotate the collision shape programmatically. Read how to do that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139478/custom-collision-shape-appears-in-wrong-position/76139693#76139693).

The following instance method will solve your problem:

```
@MainActor func offsetBy(rotation: simd_quatf,
                         translation: SIMD3<Float>) -> ShapeResource
```